# HTML/PHP form data validation?

Tags: php, html, validation

I'm new at coding

Just looking for some help on this matter,
My code is a snippet from a table that I am designing

What i'm wanting to do is have the date input box disabled unless the first drop down = 'NO', the drop down data is pulled from an SQL query

```html
        <td><select name="DATEACC">
            <?php 
              $options = array(' ','YES','NO');
              $output = '';
              for( $i=0; $i<count($options); $i++ ) {
                  $output .= '<option ' 
                   . ( $Row['custdateaccepted'] == $options[$i] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' 
                   . $options[$i] 
                   . '</option>';
              }
              echo $output;?>
            </select></td>

        <td><input type="date" name="ADVDATE" value="<?php echo $Row['dateadvised'];?>"></td>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: use jquery for that...

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: You can set the date input to readonly based on the value of $Row['custdateaccepted'] when the page first loads - but to change it when the dropdown is changed on the page you would need Javascript (jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript for this. If you have a unique row id $rowid as 1,2,3 etc

```
<td><select name="DATEACC" onChange="dateEnable(this)" id="DATEACC_$Row['id']">
        <?php 
          $options = array(' ','YES','NO');
          $output = '';
          for( $i=0; $i<count($options); $i++ ) {
              $output .= '<option value="'.$options[$i].'"' 
               . ( $Row['custdateaccepted'] == $options[$i] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' 
               . $options[$i] 
               . '</option>';
          }
          echo $output;?>
        </select></td>

    <td><input id="ADVDATE_$Row['id']" type="date" name="ADVDATE" value="<?php echo $Row['dateadvised'];?>"></td>
```

in javascript

```
function dateEnable(dropdown){
  var id = dropdown.id;
  var rowid = id.split('_');
  var myselect_value = dropdown.value;
  if(myselect_value == 'NO') {
    document.getElementById('ADVDATE'+'_'+rowid[1]).disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ADVDATE'+'_'+rowid[1]).disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This method works, however it only works for the first row of the table. Each row has a DATEACC yes/no drop down, but only the top row gets disabled

Comment: Then you need to specify different id to SELECT and ADVDATE in each row. Do you have a row id for that table ?

Comment: The table is built entirely from an SQL query where each row value is referenced as $Row. I'm not sure if this is what you mean - I am a total beginner in this field

Comment: is there any id. like $Row['id']?

Answer (score 0):

Just disable your date input at the start

```
<input type="date" id="ADVDATE" name="ADVDATE" value="<?php echo $Row['dateadvised'];?>" disabled>
```

and enable it using js/jquery when you have your desired value in dropdown

```
$('[name=DATEACC]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'DESIRED_VALUE')
        $('[name=ADVDATE]').enable();
});
```

Comment: This sounds like an easy solution, however i'm unsure how to implement it, I've disabled the date advised input, how do I implement the script?

Answer (score 0):

Without using jQuery you could try:

### javascript

```
function enabletextfield(e){
    var el=typeof( e.target )!=='undefined' ? e.target : e.srcElement;
    var value=el.options[ el.options.selectedIndex ].value;
    var txtfield=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"][name="ADVDATE"]')[0];
    txtfield.disabled = value=='NO' ? false : true;
}
```

### html

```
        <select name='DATEACC' id='DATEACC' onchange='enabletextfield(event)'>
            <option value='MAYBE'>MAYBE
            <option value='NO'>No
            <option value='Yes'>Yes
        </select>
        <input type="date" name="ADVDATE" value="Some value or other" disabled=true />
```

Obviously change the name of the select menu to suit and add the correct value from the db to the date input box